# How do I get an element from the list of element in js, which has a custom attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox, radio-button

I want to get all element that has costume `value` attribute from list of same element in jQuery.

I have this following HTML form :

```
<label>name <input type="text" name="name" value="value"></label>
<label>value1 <input type="radio" name="name1" value="value1"></label>
<label>value2 <input type="radio" name="name1" value="value2"></label>
<label>value3 <input type="radio" name="name1" value="value3"></label>
<label>value4 <input type="checkbox" name="name2[]" value="value4"></label>
<label>value5 <input type="checkbox" name="name2[]" value="value5"></label>
```

And i did try this following code :

```
form = $('form');
form_data = {
    'name':'test value',
    'name1':'value2',
    'name2[check]':'value5',
};
$.each(form_data,function(i,v){
    input = form.find('[name="'+i+'"]');
    inputtype = input.attr('type');

    if(inputtype == 'checkbox' || inputtype == 'radio'){
        input.has('[value="'+v+'"]').prop('checked',true);
    }else{
        input.val(v);
    }
});
```

But when i try `input.has('[value="'+v+'"]')` for get same element attribute then i did not return any element to checked that element.. !
any solution for this..?

Comment: In your if it looks like you are checking if the type is radio and checkbox at the same time, which will never be the case try to change the && to || maybe that helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter`, this will reduce the variable `input` to those only have a value that is equal to variable `v`

Here is the snippet.

```js
$(function() {

  var form = $('form');

  var form_data = {
    'name': 'test value',
    'name1': 'value2',
    'name2[]': 'value5',
  };

  $.each(form_data, function(i, v) {
    var input = form.find('[name="' + i + '"]');
    var inputtype = input.attr('type');

    if (inputtype == 'checkbox' || inputtype == 'radio') {
      input.filter(function() {return this.value === v;}).prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      input.val(v);
    }
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label>name <input type="text" name="name" value="value"></label>
  <label>value1 <input type="radio" name="name1" value="value1"></label>
  <label>value2 <input type="radio" name="name1" value="value2"></label>
  <label>value3 <input type="radio" name="name1" value="value3"></label>
  <label>value4 <input type="checkbox" name="name2[]" value="value4"></label>
  <label>value5 <input type="checkbox" name="name2[]" value="value5"></label>
</form>
```

For more docs: http://api.jquery.com/filter/